# How come I cannot access this global variable in my console?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How come I cannot access this global variable in my console?

```
let url;

$("li").click(function(){
    let url =  $(this).text();
    console.log(url);
});
```

The console prints out whenever I click, but if I type in `console.log(url)` manually, the console returns `undefined`. It seems to me that it can work locally but not globally. I want what's clicked in the list to be accessed through a global variable.

My goal is to store the text which I clicked in a list so it can be accessed somewhere in another page or app as a string in a **global** variable, not a local one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You only need to declare your global variable once. Writing `let url` again creates a new instance of the variable, which is **scoped to the function**.

So you code should be:

```
let url;

$("li").click(function(){
    url =  $(this).text();
    console.log(url);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Because your **global variable** is hidden in the `function` by **inner variable** with the **same name**. Rename one of them or just remove `let` from the second, if you consider them to be the same.

```
let url;

$("li").click(function(){
   url =  $(this).text();
   console.log(url);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are overwriting the `url` variable locally when you redeclare it with the `let` keyword. This means that you are creating a new, locally scoped `url` variable, separate from the global one which is still undefined.

Just reassign it and it should work.

```
let url;

$("li").click(function(){
    url =  $(this).text(); // remove the `let`
    console.log(url);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `url` at the top of your code and the `url` in the function are different variables because of the `let` definition of work. The first `url` is globally accessibly via console. But you did not assign a value to this variable. Thus it is `undefined`. Because of this when you hit `console.log(url)` manually, you get the `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the actual meaning of `let` and `var`. They are different.

The difference lies in the scope of their use. `var` is used to set up a scope to the function block inside which it is used or inside the code block. So you can easily declare `var` with same name in multiple functions/code blocks like this

```
function test(){
    var test1 = 5;
    console.log(test1);  //gives output
    var test1 = 6;
    console.log(test1);  //gives output
}
```

But the variables declared with `let` are not like `var` they are accessed first by the function inside which they are declared. And if it finds that the `let` already uses this variable name then it will not allow you to create a new one with the same name.

```
let test1 = 5;
console.log(test1);  //gives output
let test1 = 6; //gives error since it is already declared
```

So, the easy way to understand is that `let` allows to declare the variable only once in global scope. Later you can just change the value but cannot declare again